# HTML form to jason

Tags: html, json, parsing

So to start off, I am quite new to programming in general so please be forgiving. I am trying to store the form input in a JSON file. But I get a

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$json' am I missing a semicolon or is there something wrong in the structure of my code, or am I missing parts completely ?

```
<?php

if ( !empty ($_POST) ) {

    //Convert data to JSON

    $PostArray = array (
        "Voornaam" => $_POST['Voornaam'],
        "Achternaam" => $_POST['Achternaam'],
        "Adres" => $_POST['Adres'],
        "Postcode" => $_POST['Postcode'],
        "Woonplaats" => $_POST['Woonplaats'],
        "BSN" => $_POST['BSN'],
        "Geboortedatum" => $_POST['Geboortedatum']
    )


$json = json_encode( $PostArray );
//Checken voor errors.
if (json_last_error()) {
 exit("We have an error")
}

$file = 'registratie.json';
//Write to file
file_put_contents( $file, $json, FILE_APPEND);
}

?>

<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Bronnen</title>
  <meta name="Marco" content="">
  <meta name="Bronnen- Form" content="">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

  <!-- CSS stylesheet-->
  <link href="assets/CSS/placeholder.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>

 <div class="container">
    <form action="index.php" method="post">

        <fieldset>
        <div class="Form-Group">
             <label for="Voornaam">Voornaam:</label><br>
            <input type="text" class="Form-Control" name="Voornaam"><br>
         </div>
         <div class="Form-Group">
            <label for="Achternaam">Achternaam:</label><br>
            <input type="text" class="Form-Control" name="Achternaam"><br>
         </div>
         <div class="Form-Group">
            <label for="Adres">Adres:</label><br>
            <input type="text" class="Form-Control" name="Adres"><br>
        </div>
        <div class="Form-Group">
            <label for="Postcode">Postcode:</label><br>
            <input type="text" class="Form-Control" name="Postcode"><br>
        </div>
        <div class="Form-Group">
            <label for="Woonplaats">Woonplaats:</label><br>
            <input type="text" class="Form-Control" name="Woonplaats"><br>
        </div>
        <div class="Form-Group">
            <label for="BSN">BSN:</label><br>
            <input type="number" class="Form-Control" name="BSN"><br>
        </div>
        <div class="Form-Group">
            <label for="Geboortedatum">Geboortedatum:</label><br>
            <input type="date" name="Geboortedatum" id="datepicker"><br><br>
            <div class="Sumbit-button">
            <input type="submit" value="Submit" class="Submit" name="ok">
        </div> 
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Unexpected _ _ _ _ means that was not expected by php so look before it. You're missing a `;` after the closing bracket here: `$_POST['Geboortedatum'] )`